# NgIf not displaying even though expression is true

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show specific html code based on 'item' value. For that I have duplicated 10 ng-containers with *ngIf directive. First 9 works correct, but the last one do not want to display even though expression is true.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="item == '1'">
    *works*
</ng-container>
//...2,3,4,5,6,7,8,
<ng-container *ngIf="item == '9'">
    *works*
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="item == '10'">
   //Do not want to display even if item has '10' value
</ng-container>
```

The funniest thing is that even if I type `*ngIf="true"`  in last ng-container it still dont want to display data

```
component 

ngOnInit() {
    this.context = this.router.url.replace('/faq/sections/', '').slice(0, -2);
    this.item = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  }
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="context == 'instructions'">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item == '1'"></ng-container>
    //...2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
   <ng-container *ngIf="item == '10'">
    <h2>text</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 p-3 text-center">
        <img src="assets/money-outside.svg" alt="qiwi">
        <p class="mt-3">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 p-3 text-center">
        <img src="assets/phonenmoney.svg" alt="qiwi">
        <p class="mt-3">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 p-3 text-center">
        <img src="assets/inst-q-3.svg" alt="qiwi">
        <p class="mt-3">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 p-3 text-center">
        <img src="assets/book-in-6.svg" alt="qiwi">
        <p class="mt-3">text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: There's nothing in the above code that would indicate where the problem is. You'll need to provide more of your code for us to help you troubleshoot it. Can you provide the full view code?

Comment: Here's a working version to demonstrate that the above HTML is not the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7edcc

Comment: @Muirik added more details

Comment: Can you print the item in the template and make sure the value is '10'.

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha Yes, it is. Like I said I even tried to put *ngIf="true" and it didnt help

Comment: I updated the stackblitz with more of your view code. The fact that it's still working suggests that the issue is probably not in your HTML: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s7edcc

Comment: @Muirik I wonder is there any limits of using ng-container in one template? Like I have a lot of them

Comment: Thinking out loud here. Could it be possible that when the item is 10 the context  is not equal to  'instructions'

Comment: I can't think of any reason why there would be a limit. Of course, having a lot of them increases the chances that you have a syntax issue somewhere that you're not catching/seeing. Can't you use an `*ngFor` to iterate over an array and limit your `ng-containers`?

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha, that'd be worth checking for sure. I'd console log the relevant values to make sure that the issue isn't simply that. I'd want to rule that out first for sure.

Comment: Also, @Massaget, having that many `ng-containers` is usually a give-away that you'd be better off handling more of the logic and data transformation in the component itself. Your view code shouldn't need to be that repetitive.

Comment: @Massaget if it possible can your reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Comment: @Muirik Guys, I am sorry, I am stupid. Problem here in 'context' variable. I was using .slice(0, -2) to cut from '../instructions/9' single number and leave just string 'instructions', and now 10 has 2 digits and it made it 'instructions/' so I didn't pass first ngIf with context

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha found mistake

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured it out, @Massaget.

Comment: Have you considered using *ngFor. That way it only displays as many items as you pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Add another '='
Change to this:
*ngIf="context === 'instructions'"